# MakeAppx.exe not Found while trying to build an app in Visual Studio 19

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

**I tried adding MakePriExeFullPath environment variable manually which didn't help.**

**Does someone know how to fix this?**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       File 'MakeAppx.exe' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798187 for more information.  Dash_DOC

**The executable is located at:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\makeappx.exe

**[UPDATE] I even repaired VS19 ,still no luck**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Dash_DOC, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Dash_DOC -> C:\Users\Sahil Uzumaki\source\repos\Dash_DOC\Dash_DOC\bin\x64\Debug\Dash_DOC.exe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1020,5): error APPX1639: File 'MakeAppx.exe' not found. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798187 for more information.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you install the UWP development workload while install VS19? More [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-4---choose-workloads).

Comment: Biswapriyo yes I had done that

Comment: Run this command `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64` in cmd. Then type `where MakeAppx.exe`. If this shows the path then its installed but something wrong in VS.

Comment: this was the output :-     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvars64.bat x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.2.3
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

Comment: yup,i it's installed C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build>where MakeAppx.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\makeappx.exe

Comment: well thanks for trying, I should reinstall it I suppose.

Comment: I'm still open to suggestions guys

Comment: @SahilMahale - You should include all vital information in the question body instead of a commentary.  Without the vital information in the question, it will be difficult to answer this question, in it's current form.  (I am asking you to put the information about the location of the executable in your question body)

Comment: @ Ramhound I've updated the details as per your instructions